# ToTask makes OnCompleted execute on different thread

Tags: task-parallel-library, system.reactive

Code:

```cs
var sc = new TestScheduler();

Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), sc)
          .ToTask()
          .ToObservable()
          .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("on next: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId), 
             () => Console.WriteLine("on complete: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
          .Subscribe();

Console.WriteLine("call: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
sc.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks);
```

Output:

```
call: 11
on next: 8
on complete: 8
```

If you remove both ToTask and ToObservable then everything will execute on the same thread. It seems to me that TPL schedules OnCompleted to Task Pool somehow, but I can't find it in the source code.

Can anybody help me understand what is going on here?

DotNetFiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/epqTAG

Comment: This is another case where your shouldn't mix your monads. As a general rule you should keep your processing in `Task<T>` or in `IObservable<T>` and only change monads if you absolutely need to.

Comment: I have some services returning Task<T> that need to be processed in Rx way. So I don't really have a choice here.

Comment: That's fine. If you absolutely need to then all good. It's the changing back and forth that causes grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.ToObservable()` uses `Task.ContinueWith()` to add a Task continuation to trigger the observable when the task completes.  By default, `Task.ContinueWith()` schedules the continuation on the task pool.

Rx.Net recently added an overload of `ToObservable` that accepts an `IScheduler`.

See the the Rx.Net [github issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/21) for more details.